# Successive conditions to subtract amount in one col from other cols

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, logic, subtraction

I have a df as follows. I would like to subtract col `d` from the other columns using the following rules:

- No result can be negative
- If `d` can be divided equally and subtracted across from `a:c` without generating a negative, then subtract an equal amount across cols
- else, if `d` can be divided and subtracted equally from `b:c` and the remainder from `a` without generating a negative, then subtract from cols
- else, if `d` can be subtracted from `c`, the remainder from `b`, and the subsequent remainder from `a`  without generating a negative, then subtract from cols
- else, if `d` can be subtracted from from `b` and the remainder from `a` without generating a negative, then subtract from cols
- else, subtract from `a`

df:

```
structure(list(a = c(0, 6.22, 1.2, 0.22, 0.24), b = c(8.88, 1.08, 
0.25, 0, 0), c = c(13.76, 0, 19.61, 0, 0), d = c(-2.64, -0.3, 
-11.06, -0.22, -0.24)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), c = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

starting table:

```
a     b     c      d
0     8.88  13.76  -2.64
6.22  1.08  0      -0.3
1.2   0.25  19.61  -11.06
0.22  0     0      -0.22
0.24  0     0      -0.24
```

desired result:

```
a     b     c      d
0     7.56  12.44  -2.64
6.22  0.78  0      -0.3
1.2   0.25  8.55   -11.06
0     0     0      -0.22
0     0     0      -0.24
```

Comment: This feels a bit more like producing software to spec rather than helping you get past something you're stuck on.  If you at least posted what you've tried so far, and where you're getting hung up, it'd feel a bit more collaborative and less like soliciting free labor.  (Granted, it's a fine line on SO - but this is a little too far over the line, imho.)

Comment: For complex conditionals like this, consider the `dplyr` `case_when()` function

Comment: @JonMinton, thanks. I'll play around with that. I appreciate the suggestion of tools to use. This is a more complex task than I am used to and could use some pointers on possible approaches.